# Optimizing the SQL Query for Calculating account balance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following tables which are BankDetails and Transactiondetails. Using these two tables, I want to get the current balance of the account name.

Tables:

```
Create table Bankdetails
(
AccName varchar(50),
AccNo int,
OpBal numeric(18,2)
)

Create table Trandetails
(
AccNo int,
Amount numeric(18,2),
Trantype varchar(10)
)
```

Insert scripts for both tables:

```
insert into Bankdetails values('A', 12345, 30000.00)
insert into Bankdetails values('B', 13345, 30000.00)
insert into Bankdetails values('C', 14545, 30000.00)
insert into Bankdetails values('D', 15045, 30000.00)

insert into Trandetails values(12345, 5000.00, 'Credit')
insert into Trandetails values(13345, 5000.00, 'Debit')
insert into Trandetails values(15045, 5000.00, 'Debit')
insert into Trandetails values(13345, 5000.00, 'Credit')
insert into Trandetails values(12345, 5000.00, 'Debit')
insert into Trandetails values(13345, 5000.00, 'Debit')
insert into Trandetails values(14545, 5000.00, 'Credit')
insert into Trandetails values(15045, 5000.00, 'Debit')
insert into Trandetails values(14545, 5000.00, 'Debit')
```

Output would be like this:

```
AccName Accno    CurrBal
  A     12345   30000.00 
  B     13345   25000.00
  C     14545   30000.00
  D     15045   20000.00
```

I need Account Holdername, Account No and current balance using the above two tables.

Below is my query, I want to get optimized query i.e without using subqueries if possible.
**Note:** In my case, credit = amount added into account and debit = amount subracted from account.

```
Select bd.accname, bd.accno, 
(bd.opbal - isnull((select SUM(Amount) from Trandetails where Trantype = 'Debit' and accno = bd.accno group by accno),0) + isnull((select SUM(Amount) from Trandetails where Trantype = 'Credit'  and accno = bd.accno group by accno),0)) as Bal
From Bankdetails BD inner join Trandetails TD on td.AccNo = bd.AccNo
group by bd.accno, bd.accname, bd.opbal
```

My apologies for not following proper naming conventions for tables. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Paresh J

Comment: I'd usually recommend, rather than having a `TranType` column just allowing the `Amount` column to contain both positive and negative values and using a convention (e.g. positive is credit, negative is debit). It makes most useful queries far easier. Otherwise, with your current design, you're probably missing a `CHECK `constraint to *prevent* `Amount` from being negative - unless you want people applying negative credits?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: TranType kept to capture transaction type. In actual table it contains more details than just CREDIT & Debit. Hence cant drop these column from the table.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: any other optimize solution possible? i mean not much complex query.

Comment: In that case I'd still recommend appropriate `CHECK` constraints - and probably still *store* debits as negative amounts and credits as positive - like I say, it makes most queries on these tables a lot easier if you can trivially `SUM` the amount column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to generate first the sum for each transaction type, `Debit` and `Credit`. With that, join it to the `Bankdetails` to compute for the current balance.

```
;with cte as(
    select
        AccNo,
        Credit = sum(case when TranType = 'Credit' then Amount else 0 end),
        Debit = sum(case when TranType = 'Debit' then Amount else 0 end)
    from Trandetails
    group by
        AccNo
)
select
    bd.AccName,
    bd.AccNo,
    CurrBal = bd.opBal - c.Debit + c.Credit
from BankDetails bd
inner join cte c
    on c.Accno = bd.Accno
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that care about performance,here goes;

```
Select   B.AccName
        ,B.AccNo
        ,(B.OpBal + SUM( Case When TranType = 'Credit' Then Amount Else Amount* -1 End)) CurrBal
From Bankdetails B
Left Join Trandetails T
On B.AccNo = T.AccNo
Group By B.AccName, B.AccNo, B.OpBal;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bba7d/1/0)**

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
    Bankdetails.AccName
    , Bankdetails.AccNo
    , Bankdetails.OpBal 
        + SUM(CASE WHEN TranType = 'Credit' THEN  Amount ELSE 0 END)
        - SUM(CASE WHEN TranType = 'Debit' THEN  Amount ELSE 0 END)
    AS 'CurrBal'
FROM Trandetails
    INNER JOIN Bankdetails ON Bankdetails.AccNo = Trandetails.AccNo
GROUP BY Bankdetails.AccNo, Bankdetails.AccName
```

Comment: It would be great if you can explain your code. That will help the OP as well as other SO users. :)

Comment: There are couples of errors with above solution. 1. Ambiguous column name 'AccNo'. 2. Column 'Bankdetails.AccName' is invalid in the select list since You have not included other column names in GROUP BY

Comment: still missing `Bankdetails.OpBal` in Group by