# column 'PostedVoucher.stat_flag' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi everyone I'm trying to select the account name (stat_leger) ,  total debit from stat_leger column  where stat_flag column  = d and total credit from stat_leger  where stat_flag column  = c  and group by stat_leger I need column to ruturn like this

```
Account Name(stat_leger) |  total debit |  total credit 
                         |              |
     acc1                |      20      |    0.00
     acc2                |      30      |    15
     acc3                |      40      |     20
```

I tried

```
select DISTINCT stat_leger , sum(stat_amount) as deb  
from PostedVoucher
where branch='1' and stat_flag ='c' group by stat_leger

union 

select  DISTINCT stat_leger , sum(stat_amount) as cred
from PostedVoucher
where branch='1' and stat_flag ='d' group by stat_leger
```

but it return the total debit and credit in same column deb like this

```
Account Name(stat_leger) |     deb 
     acc1                |     0.00       
     acc1                |      20     
     acc2                |      15
     acc2                |      30      
     acc3                |      40      
     acc3                |      20
```

also when I tried

```
 select  stat_leger ,
 ( select sum(stat_amount) as deb  where stat_flag ='c'   ) 
 from PostedVoucher
  where branch='1'  group by (stat_leger);
```

but it returns error 
Column 'PostedVoucher.stat_flag' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no need for subquery. You can add where condition in you main `WHERE` clause. Check the below query:

Try this:

```
SELECT stat_leger, SUM(stat_amount)
FROM PostedVoucher
WHERE branch='1' AND stat_flag ='c'
GROUP BY (stat_leger);
```

Comment: it will not return data I need , It will return only total of credit I need the total of credit and debit

Comment: If you want total of credit and debit then just remove AND stat_flag ='c' from my query, SUM(stat_amount) will fetch you total of both credit and debit.

Comment: I want both total debit and total credit but  not same column like what I write in my question

Comment: check answer by wewesthemenace in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27119834/optimizing-the-sql-query-for-calculating-account-balance